# Bootstrap collapsable menu breaks for tablet version while works for phone version

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By default break point in bootstrap is 767px but i need to break it at 980px so that collapsible menu shows for screens below 981px screens.

Current script works fine (In a way with default behavior of bootstrap) for screens small than 768px.

I want to add same phone `nav` behavior up-to 980px screen. but it breaks for tablet version.

Main problems is that it doesnt add vertical scroll bar as in case of phone version as a result i can see of scroll down to other menu items if menu is large than screen size.

JSbin example and screen shot of issue in my case

[jsbin.com/yivihihota/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/yivihihota/1/edit)

http://jsbin.com/yivihihota

**for screens smaller than 768 pixels**
[image]
**For screens between 768px - 980px**
[image]

NO SCROLL BAR SHOWS UP for 786px - 980px version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this media-query in your css.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width : 980px){
  .navbar-collapse.in{
    overflow-y: auto !important;
  }
}
```